# Unit test Async await method assert fails if (Run all test) is called but test are passing if I run one by one

Tags: c#, unit-testing, async-await

Unit test Async await method assert fails if (Run all test) is called but test are passing if I run one by one.

Each method has no dependency on each other.

unit test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataById()
{
    ////Act.
    var output = await Service.GetDataByID(1);
    ////Assert.
    Assert.IsNotNull(output);
    ////Act.
    output = await Service.GetDataByID(2);
    ////Assert.
    Assert.IsNull(output);
}
```

Comment: What is `Service.GetDataByID`?

Comment: Are you using a transaction inside of GetDataByID? Also, I recommend ending any async functions with "Async". So, in this case, I would call your functions "GetDataByIdAsync."

Comment: And, also, are there any transactions used by any of the other test methods that you're calling?

Comment: New instance of the test class will be created for every test method. So problem seems is inside `Service.GetDataByID`, which you didn't show.

Comment: You have two assertions in one test, which one failing?

Answer (score 1):

if you have any mock setup before each test then reset those mock after each (TearDown).

1. avoid sharing variable or state in asynchronous context

```

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataById()
{
     ////Act.
    var output = await Service.GetDataByID(1);
     ////Assert.
    Assert.IsNotNull(output);
     ////Act.
    var output2 = await Service.GetDataByID(2); // <-- new variable
    ////Assert.
    Assert.IsNull(output2);
}
```

```

2. [Assert only "one thing"](https://mfranc.com/unit-testing/good-unit-test-one-assert/) multiple asserts are OK, just single result from one action

```

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataByIdWhenExists()
{
     //Act.
    var output = await Service.GetDataByID(1);
     ////Assert.
    Assert.IsNotNull(output);
}

[TestMethod]
public async Task GetDataByIdWhenNotExists()
{
     //Act.
    var output = await Service.GetDataByID(2);
     //Assert.
    Assert.IsNotNull(output);
}
```

```

Answer (score 0):

It was the Effort.DbConnectionFactory's CreatePersistent() method i change it to CreateTransient() now it is working.

Thanks for the help guys.